# How do I get help for a specific package?

Tags: functions, packages

I am at a phase of cleaning up my choice of plugins and I want to read the documentation provided by a package through vim it self.

With that in mind, I don't know a way to:

- get to the top of the documentation for a specific package
- see find functions or 'g' settings for a package so that I can call `:h` on them

An example of such is the package `elzr/vim-json`. I don't know what functions or settings this package exposes. Auto-completing `:json` or something gives nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A feature that isn't documented is a useless feature.
>
> `:h design-documented`

In theory, you can do `:h local-additions` (towards the bottom of `:h`) which will show you an index of all local plugins that you have installed (if they included documentation).

> get to the top of the documentation for a specific package

Most documentation you can do `:h {package-name}` to get the documentation. You can use wildcards and tab completion to help you search. You may also like to use `<c-d>` list out completions.

Example:

```
:h win*(<tab>
:h win*(<c-d>
```

You can also search help files via `:helpgrep` (similar to `:vimgrep`). Use `:helpgrep /{pattern}/` to search the helpfiles for `{pattern}`. The results will be put into the quickfix list. Use `:cnext`/`:cprev` to go thought the list and `:copen` to open the quickfix window.

> see find functions or 'g' settings for a package so that I can call :h on them

It is up to the documentation author to write good help tags otherwise you are at the mercy of reading the entire help file or searching.

> An example of such is the package elzr/vim-json. I don't know what functions or settings this package exposes.

Sadly, [elzr/vim-json](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json) does not ship with Vim help documentation. From what I can tell it only has a github readme file.

Personally, I tend to avoid plugins that do not provide good Vim help documentation.